# Reactjs Usestate hook not sending data properlty to database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, use-state

i know this is very easy question , but i am new with MERN technology. i am sending my data using  React frontend  to json-server npm module , all the codes works properly even though the data stored to backend smoothly . but the problem is that frontend data send extra fields to backend server which i don't want  . [you can see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10xeW.png)  there are 3 object 1st two object i have stored manually and third one i stored using React frontend application . the third one json-object stored  [extra fields are highlited  here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UklYe.png) which i dont want . i am upload my working code please guide me .

```
 //RegisterUser react Component :
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
import loginImage from '../images/login2.jpeg';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { addUser} from '../Service/api';

const initialValues = {
name:"",
username:"",
email:"",
phone:"",
 }

const RegisterUser = () => {

const [user , setUser]= useState([initialValues]);
const { name,username, email, phone,} = user;



const style = {
    color: 'black',
    textAlign:'center'
  };

  const onValueChange= (e)=>{
      console.log(e.target.Object);
      setUser({...user, [e.target.name]:e.target.value})
      console.log(user)
  }

  const addUserDetails= async()=>{
   
    await addUser(user);
  }

 return (
    <div>
         <div>
    
    <div className="container login-container">
    <div className="row login-form-1">
    <div className="col-md-6 ">
    <h3 style={style}>Registration</h3>
          <form>
            <div className="form-group">
               <input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={(e)=>                            onValueChange(e)} name="name" value={name} placeholder="Your Name *"  />
            </div>
            
            <div className="form-group">
              <input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={(e)=>    onValueChange(e)} name="username" value={username} placeholder="username *"  />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input type="text" className="form-control"  onChange={(e)=> onValueChange(e)} name="email"  value={email} placeholder="Your Email *"  />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={(e)=> onValueChange(e)} name="phone" value={phone}  placeholder="Mobile Number *"  />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input type="submit" className="btnSubmit" onClick={()=> addUserDetails()} defaultValue="Login" />
            </div>
          </form>
          </div>
          <div className="col">
          
              <img className="loginpic" src={loginImage} alt="login Image"/>
              <div className="col">
          <NavLink  to="/login" className="signupIs" >I have already     account</NavLink>
    </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    </div>
          </div>
    </div>

    
 


    
)
   }

    export default RegisterUser
```

Api file

```
    import axios from 'axios';

    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3003/users';

    export const getUsers = async ()=>{
   return await axios.get(url);
    }

  export const addUser = async(user)=>{
   return await axios.post(url,user); 
    }
```

again i am informing that the code is running no error while executing , but the issue is getting extra data field from React Frontend

Comment: Looks like your only issue is that you're setting state an an array initially when it shouldn't be an array: `const [user , setUser]= useState(initialValues);`. Notice that I removed the brackets `[ ]`

Answer (score 0):

When you first initialize your "user", you create it as *an array*:

```
const [user , setUser]= useState([initialValues]);
                              // ^---- here ---^
```

Then later you interpret the array as an object and add properties to it:

```
setUser({...user, [e.target.name]:e.target.value})
```

When doing so, that initial "user" would be a property called `"0"` since it's the first element of the array.  So those "extra properties" are simply the initial state.

It sounds like what you intended was not to use an array at all:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(initialValues);
```